# Get Random String in strings.xml

Tags: android, string, checkbox, random, textview

I have strings in my Values->Strings.xml file, and when I click a button I want to show a random string from this file. My main.xml has checkboxes like this:

For example:

- volkswagen (Checkbox)
- audi(Checkbox)
- Mercedes(Checkbox)
- Ford(Unchecked)

when user clicks the 'generete a car' button, the system will get the clicked brand's array items randomly.

The Mercedes array has c180-e250-e200-c120 etc.
The Audi array has a1-a2-a3-a4 etc.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Generate Car"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Butona Basın !"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="VolksWagen"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:checked="false" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Audi"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:checked="false" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mercedes"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:checked="false" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ford"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:checked="false" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Passat"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="A6"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="C180 AMG"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Mustang"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Volkswagen"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Audi"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/checkBox" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Mercedes"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox4" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Ford"
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView5" />
```

and main activity;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tvvolks = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textvolks);
        TextView txaudi = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textaudi);
        TextView txford = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textford);
        TextView txmerc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textmerc);
        Button generate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        //When pressed button check to checkbox and whole actived get a random string at string.xml

    }
}
```

string.xml

```
  <string-array name="Mercedes">
    <item>C180</item>
    <item>E250</item>
    <item>etc.</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="Audi">
    <item>A1</item>
    <item>A2</item>
</string-array> <string-array name="Ford">
<item>Mustang</item>
<item>Fusion</item>
<item>Focus</item>
```

Comment: OK. Where is the code to generate a random number, get an array element with that index and a Click listener to fire that and display it somewhere (in a TextView, I suppose)?

Comment: Where did you add it?

Comment: it will get on strings.xml and will show on textviews.if have unchecked box that box will unvisible.if the user selected vw and audi it will get on string.xml audi and vw's arrays.and will show on textvolks-textaudi others will unvisible.idk how will i add array and clicklistener pls help thx.

Comment: @DerGolem u still Here ?

Comment: You shouldn't ask other people to do your work for you. We're here to help if you have an issue, but you must have done some effort before. At least, study the `Random` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string.xml` is mainly for strings to be translated and strings to be used in other resources like layouts etc.

Since the car brands and models will not be translated, it will be better if you store them inside a static `ArrayList` or `HashMap`. Then, you can directly access them easily.

Comment: If you have questions how to get a random number, I can add it to my answer.

Comment: ok thanks for your idea but thats is examples.i will use for an another idea. :)

Comment: i foung my answer at https://vollnixx.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/android-get-random-elements-out-of-an-arraylist/ 
but thanks your comment said abi :) :)